# Dagger 2: inject an interface in a constructor

Tags: java, android, dependency-injection, dagger-2, dagger

I'm trying to learn dagger 2 but I'm confused in injecting of constructor with interface. This is my below code :

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements MainView {

    // this keyword of request dependency . At compiling process, dagger will look at all of these annotations
    //to create the exact dependency

    @Inject MainPresenter mainPresenter ;
    TextView textView ;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        textView = findViewById(R.id.textview) ;
        DaggerPresenterComponent.create().inject(this);
        textView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                mainPresenter.doThings(8555) ;
            }
        });

    }

    /**********************************/

    @Override
    public void invokeRandomViewMethod(String msg) {
        textView.setText(msg);
    }
}
```

**MainPresenter.java**

```
public class MainPresenter {

    private MainView mainView ;

    @Inject
    public MainPresenter(MainView mainView) {
        this.mainView = mainView;
    }

    public void doThings(int value){
        Random random = new Random();
        int rand= random.nextInt(value) ;
        if(mainView != null){
            mainView.invokeRandomViewMethod("You random number is "+rand);
        }
    }

public interface MainView {
    void invokeRandomViewMethod(String msg) ;
}
}
```

This is the **Module** :

```
@Module
public class PresenterModule {

    @Provides
        // this is the method that will provide the dependancy
    MainPresenter provideMainPresenter(MainView mainView){
        return new MainPresenter(mainView);
    }
}
```

And this is the **Component**

```
@Component (modules = PresenterModule.class)
public interface PresenterComponent {
    void inject(MainActivity activity) ;
}
```

When I run the code it shows me this error :

> Error:(15, 10) error: com.imennmn.hellodagger2example.MainView cannot
>   be provided without an @Provides-annotated method.
>   com.imennmn.hellodagger2example.MainView is injected at
>   com.imennmn.hellodagger2example.presenterInjection.PresenterModule.provideMainPresenter(mainView)
>   com.imennmn.hellodagger2example.MainPresenter is injected at
>   com.imennmn.hellodagger2example.MainActivity.mainPresenter
>   com.imennmn.hellodagger2example.MainActivity is injected at
>   com.imennmn.hellodagger2example.simpleInjection.DataComponent.inject(activity)

My Question is how I can provide the interface MainView by inject it with dagger and bind the MainPresenter and MainActivity ? 
Any help would be appreciated !

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By following code:

```
    MainPresenter provideMainPresenter(MainView mainView) {
        return new MainPresenter(mainView);
    }
```

You are telling dagger: *"hey, whenever I ask you to inject `MainPresenter`, construct it using `MainView`"*.
But dagger complaints, because you haven't specified how exactly he should build/acquire `MainView`.

So, in your `PresenterModule` do this:

```
    @Module
    public class PresenterModule {

        MainView mainView;

        public PresenterModule(MainView mainView) {
            this.mainView = mainView;
        }

        @Provides
        MainPresenter provideMainPresenter() {
            return new MainPresenter(mainView);
        }

    }
```

Then when building the component:

```
    DaggerPresenterComponent.builder()
                            .presenterModule(new PresenterModule(this))
                            .build();
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `provideMainPresenter` implicitly depends on a `MainView`. Dagger has no way to get it. You need to add a method to provide it:

```
@Module
public class PresenterModule {

    @Provides
    MainView provideMainView(){
        // Provide MainView here somehow so Dagger can use this to create a MainPresenter
    }

    @Provides
    // this is the method that will provide the dependancy
    MainPresenter provideMainPresenter(MainView mainView){
        return new MainPresenter(mainView);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add abstract module with `@Binds` annotation, look at my impl of : **AbstractTestSettingsFragmentModule.java**

**TestFragment.java**

```
public class TestFragment extends Fragment{

    @Inject TestFragmentContract.Presenter mPresenter;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        AndroidSupportInjection.inject(this);

    }

 }
```

**TestFragmentPresenterImpl.java**

```
public class TestFragmentPresenterImpl implements TestFragmentContract.Presenter {

    @Inject
    public TestFragmentPresenterImpl(){
    }
}
```

**AbstractTestSettingsFragmentModule.java**

```
@Module
public abstract class AbstractTestSettingsFragmentModule {

    @Binds
    @NonNull
    public abstract TestSettingsFragmentContract.Presenter testSettingsFragmentPresenterImpl(TestSettingsFragmentImpl presenter);

}
```

**ContributesModule.java**

```
   @Module
    public abstract class ContributesModule {

        @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = {AbstractTestSettingsFragmentModule.class})
        abstract TestSettingsFragment testSettingsFragment();
    }
```

**AppComponent.java**

```
@Singleton
@Component(
        modules = {
                AndroidSupportInjectionModule.class,
                ContributesModule.class,
                AppModule.class,
              })
public interface AppComponent extends AndroidInjector<DaggerApplication> {

    void inject(TheApplication theApplication);

    @Override
    void inject(DaggerApplication instance);

    @Component.Builder
    interface Builder {

        @BindsInstance
        Builder application(Application application);

        AppComponent build();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Assisted Injection with Dagger: https://dagger.dev/dev-guide/assisted-injection.html

Assisted injection is a dependency injection (DI) pattern that is used to construct an object where some parameters may be provided by the DI framework and others must be passed in at creation time (a.k.a “assisted”) by the user.